# What is the endpoint of a minio bucket?

Tags: minio, argo-workflows

I am trying to find the correct endpoint to use to connect to a minio bucket. I am running minio on a minikube cluster, and I am using argo workflows to launch pods. When I give the addresss I use to login to minio (http://127.0.0.1:29941/), I get:

> Error (exit code 1): failed to create new S3 client: Endpoint url cannot have fully qualified paths.

Or when I use minio:9000 as endpoint i get:

> Error (exit code 1): failed to put file: Get "http://minio:9000/my-bucket/?location=": dial tcp: lookup minio on 10.96.0.10:53: server misbehaving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be the name of the service with the port. In my case for argo workflow it was:
argo-artifacts:9000